# datepicker date is not accurate in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've developed a jQuery datepicker instance using the following code.

```
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({  
        inline: true,
        showButtonPanel: true, //Default Button Panel is customized in jQuery UI Soucre - Line Number : 9265 
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",//custom icon trigger -> positioned in CSS
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        //beforeShowDay:function(date){
            //var blockDates = [""];
            //var currentDateString = $.datepicker.formatDate(date);
            //return [blockDates.indexOf(currentDateString) == -1 ];
        //},
        onSelect:function(date,inst){
            if(inst.id != "to" && date != ""){
                var numOfDays = 2;
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
                date.setDate(date.getDate('mm/dd/yy') + numOfDays);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#to").datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
                    $("#to").datepicker('show');
                    $("#to").datepicker('setDate',date.toLocaleDateString());
                }, 10);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

I've got two inputs with datepicker instances. In the first I select a date and by using the date I populate the second date. When I test this on a desktop and I get the correct date. But the thing is I tested this on an iPad and the calculated date is not advanced by two days. the date is advanced by 7 months! I have no idea what's wrong with the code! any help?

**I've tested in both safari + google chrome for ipad. the result is same.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Date.getDate() does not accept any parameters.
- datepicker.setDate() happily accepts the JavaScript Date

Try revising your code like this:

```
    onSelect: function (date, inst) {
        if (inst.id != "to") {
            var numOfDays = 2;
            var date = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", date);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + numOfDays);
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            $("#to").datepicker("setDate", date);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#to").datepicker("show");
            }, 10);
        }
    }
```